# Disabling Material Design Lite toggle switch

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I'm trying to create some elements on the page with JavaScript and dress them up with the new [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io/).  It all works until I try to start disabling elements programmatically after the elements are created.

I have a few toggle switches (created by JavaScript).  When one toggles on, I want others to be disabled.

If I use:

```
toggle2.disabled = true;
```

it works great and it's disabled, but as soon as I try it like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 

if (toggle1.checked == true) {
    toggle2.disabled = true;
} else {
    toggle2.disabled = false;
}

}, 1000);
```

toggle2 is visually still active, the ripple effect works but it doesn't slide to ON so it's disabled in the background just not visually.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q08t7z17/2/) for en example (uses HTML elements but the same happens with my JS created ones)

Also, here's a [video of the problem](https://goo.gl/PCvnC3) .  In it, the third one down is disabled by `toggle3.disabled = true;` and the fourth one is disabled by the IF statement based on the second one down's state.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug with MDL itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to query the element up and then call `MaterialCheckbox.disable()` on it. Like so:

`document.querySelector('#my-checkbox').MaterialCheckbox.disable()`

Disable is a method provided by the checkbox component (implemented as a widget) so what is needed internally with all the extra elements created gets handled properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help Garbee, although I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined` when doing that. See https://jsfiddle.net/6hydumc8/

Comment: Oops,we goofed. We'll get this fixed in the next patch release. In 1.0 we didn't expose the checkbox as a widget. Super sorry, patch should be in master today for the 1.0.1 tag that will hopefully be done Friday.

Comment: Oh, @SS113 another heads up, you don't target the input itself but the element you define the js trigger on, in this case the label. https://jsfiddle.net/tpbpr9gt/  this is an updated fiddle where it will work right once the patch lands.

Comment: Thank you for the help and for the update on the patch coming up!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `disabled` HTML attribute to you `<input>`:

`<input type="checkbox" id="toggle2" class="mdl-switch__input" disabled="disabled" />`

Your try to do this was wrong. There is no disabled property of the object. You should set it by JQuery this way:

`$('input#toggle2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

I've updated [your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvgs2p9d/2/).

You don't need to use `SetInterval`. Just subscribe to `change` event of `#toggle1`.

Comment: Just tried that and it creates the same effect. Disabled, but visually not and the ripple still works and doesn't slide to ON. https://jsfiddle.net/gvgs2p9d/

Comment: Also, `toggle2.disabled = true;` is working great if it's not in the IF statement: https://goo.gl/RGnCzU

Comment: @SS113 Strange but it's not working for me in your JSFiddle.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm confused why it looks gray and un-clickable when using `toggle2.disabled = true;` by itself but any other way (yours or mine) produces a visually active toggle that has a ripple effect but not slide-able. Thanks for the help so far!